# how to get the Fee Amount for paypal

Tags: java, paypal, intellij-idea

I am currently looking at a system that implements the PayPal api. As a part of this I need to get the feeAmt() which is the fee that is paid to paypal for processing the payment.

From the documentation that I have looked at it appears that I have to implement the getExpressCheckoutDetailsReq() method in order to get the information that I want however no matter what I have tried I am struggling to do this. I should also let you know that I am currently developing my application using Java so using this is going to be best.

If any more explanation is needed please don't hesitate to ask and I will do my best to amend the post :)

Answer (score 0):

GetExpressCheckoutDetails does not include the fee because at that point no payment has been made yet.  That's the 2nd of 3 calls for Express Checkout, and until the final call is made there is no fee.

The fee amount would actually come in that final call's response:  [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).  It will come in the PAYMENTINFO_n_FEEAMT parameter, where n is the number of the payment (0,1,2,etc.)  Most likely it'll be 0 unless you're working with parallel payments.

Alternatively, you can use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to get details about transactions, including the fee, in real-time when transactions are completed on your PayPal account.

Yet another option would be to use the [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API to pull data for an individual transaction which would include the fee in a FEEAMT parameter.  Maybe that's the one you were initially thinking of..??

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there any other solution?

Comment: None of the 3 solutions I provided as options work for you?

Comment: I followed this tutorial. https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout?success=true&token=EC-0UN4180064902854K&PayerID=3WCRPEYXKWP7Q the response of step 4 should contain this information. Please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776637/commit-paypal-express-transaction